# Second update service worker doesn't work

Tags: service-worker

I hava a pwa with this sw.js:

```
const info = "versione: 1.0.0 data: 07-01-2020 12:46";
const CACHE = "pwa-offline";
const pages = [
  // some files
];

self.addEventListener("install", function (event) {
  //console.log("Install Event processing");
  self.skipWaiting();

  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {
      //console.log("Cached offline page during install");
      return cache.addAll(pages);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {
  if (event.request.method !== "GET") return;
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request)
    .then(function (response) {
      return fromCache(event.request);
    })
    
    .catch(function (error) {
      //console.log("Network request Failed. Serving content from cache: " + error);
      return fromCache(event.request);
    })
  );
});

async function fromCache(request) {
  // Check to see if you have it in the cache
  // Return response
  // If not in the cache, then return error page
  const cache = await caches.open(CACHE);
  const matching = await cache.match(request);
  if (!matching || matching.status === 404) {
    return Promise.reject("no-match");
  }
  return matching;
}

async function updateCache(request, response) {
  const cache = await caches.open(CACHE);
  return cache.put(request, response);
}
```

and index.html with this code inside:

```
 <script>
    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker
        .register("./sw.js")//, {updateViaCache: 'none'})
        .then(reg => {
          //console.log("Registration successful", reg);
        })
        .catch(e =>
          console.error("Error during service worker registration:", e)
        );
    } else {
      console.warn("Service Worker is not supported");
    }
  </script>
```

I upload the pwa in a firebase site. When I change the sw.js *(e.g. changing the date of versionDate, in this site https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle I read: "Your service worker is considered updated if it's byte-different to the one the browser already has. (We're extending this to include imported scripts/modules too.)")* and I upload, I see the new service worker is changed. But when I make a second change in sw.js and upload, the sw.js is not changed, so I can do only an update on sw.js and so to the whole site (because the sw.js caches all files of the site during the install process).
How can I update my site any time I want?

UPDATE: I watched that the problem is in android phone in desktop is ok.

UPDATE: Now also it works on android but the update is not immadiate. I see the update after some hours.

Answer (score 2):

Your service worker caches all static files on your website. Consequently, you will need to edit your `sw.js` file whenever you are updating your website. One common way to do this is to attach a version number to your static cache name, for example `pwa-offline-v1`, then bump up the version number in the `sw.js` file whenever you are pushing an update to the site. This creates a new cache and stores the updated static files to it. You can then add an `activate` event listener on the service worker to delete the former cache using a function like this.

```
const info = "versione: 1.0.0 data: 07-01-2020 12:46";
const CACHE = "pwa-offline-v1";
const pages = [
  // some files
];

self.addEventListener("install", function (event) {
  //console.log("Install Event processing");
  self.skipWaiting();

  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {
      //console.log("Cached offline page during install");
      return cache.addAll(pages);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    Promise.all(
      caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => {
        cacheNames
          .filter(cacheName => cacheName.startsWith('pwa-offline-') && cacheName !== CACHE)
          .map(cacheName => caches.delete(cacheName))
      })
    )
  );
});
```

Comment: I have this error: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) at Function.all (<anonymous>)" regarding Promise.all. I deleted Promise.all. I watched that the problem is in android phone in desktop is ok.

Comment: Now also it works on android but the update is not immadiate. I see the update after some hours.